# Create a "Command Line Tool" project from xcode, and setup and run NSApplication. The cursor in this application can't change

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I make a little tool built on "Command Line Tool" project.
Everything works well except the **Cursor** in this tool.

Here is the launch code:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    NSApplication * app = [NSApplication sharedApplication];
    MyDelegate * delegate = [[MyDelegate alloc] init];
    app.delegate = delegate;
    [app run];
    return 0;
}
```

And in MyDelegate, I create window, view, etc. However I override the `resetCursorRects` function in the View, but nothing happened.

If the same code run in an Application project, everything will be OK.

All the thing I tried include:

> 1. Make a subclass from NSApplication and override run function to handle uesr event.
> 2. Make a NSTrackingArea in the view to update cursor.
> 3. Perform selector(run) on mainThread and wait until done.

However they didn't work at all.

Now all the reason I guessed is the function `NSApplicationMain(argc, argv)` is not equal with `[app run]`.

What's the difference? Can any one help me?

PS: If I use `NSApplicationMain(argc, argv)`, xcode will give me an error that I must have a bundle and Info.plist. I don't want create an application, because it's to fat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A program which is not a bundled app is, by default, a background-only process. A bundled app is, by default, a foreground-capable process. (One can set the `LSUIElement` key in an app's Info.plist to change that.)

Only the active app can set the cursor. A background-only or UI element (a.k.a. accessory) process can't become the active app.

If you want your program to be able to be activated and control the cursor, you can use `[NSApp setActivationPolicy:NSApplicationActivationPolicyRegular]` to make it a foreground-capable app process. Note that this will make it appear in the Dock and Command-Tab application switcher (but with a generic-executable icon).

Of course, it's just easier and simpler to make your program a full-fledged bundled app.

Comment: Wow, that's amazing. And the actually Policy I need is NSApplicationActivationPolicyAccessory. Thank you very much :D.